# DirectX Trying to create shader

Tags: directx, shader

I'm new to DirectX and I'm trying to compile a shader but I keep getting an error. Could someone help me out with it please?

The error I get is..

Unhandled exception at 0x00D06A6D in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC.

and that's when it hits the line:

```
    m_pDevice->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &m_pVS);
```

DX Code:

```
ID3DBlob *VS, *PS;
ID3DBlob* VSerrorBlob = nullptr;
ID3DBlob* PSerrorBlob = nullptr;

D3DCompileFromFile(L"shader.fx", 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, "VShader",  "vs_4_0_level_9_1",
    D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, &VS, &VSerrorBlob );

D3DCompileFromFile(L"shader.fx", 0, D3D_COMPILE_STANDARD_FILE_INCLUDE, "PShader",  "ps_4_0_level_9_1",
    D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, 0, &PS, &PSerrorBlob );

m_pDevice->CreateVertexShader(VS->GetBufferPointer(), VS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &m_pVS);
m_pDevice->CreatePixelShader(PS->GetBufferPointer(), PS->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &m_pPS);
```

Shader Code:

```
    struct VOut
{
    float4 position : SV_POSITION;
    float4 color : COLOR;
};

VOut VShader(float4 position : POSITION, float4 color : COLOR)
{
    VOut output;

    output.position = position;
    output.color = color;

    return output;
}


float4 PShader(float4 position : SV_POSITION, float4 color : COLOR) : SV_TARGET
{
    return color;
}
```

Comment: You should take a look at the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929) and the [tutorials](https://directxtk.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started) for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the HRESULTs returned by your calls to D3DCompileFromFile, it probably failed. If so, check the string inside your errors blob to find out why.

Comment: Ah thanks. It says it can't find the file. I have my shader.fx file in the Project directory (not the source code). That is the correct path for that directory right? To be more clear it looks like... Project -> Header Files | Source Files | Resource Files | shader.fx

Comment: The default working directory is the Project Directory, so the file paths will be relative to there.